# How can I read a file's contents directly with Perl's Net::FTP?

Tags: perl

I want to get the file from one host to another host. We can get the file using the [NET::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libnet) module.  In that module we can use the `get` method to get the file. But I want the file contents instead of the file. I know that using the `read` method we can read the file contents. But how do I call the `read` function and how do I get the file contents?

Comment: Is it important to keep using the FTP protocol or is any protocol which solves the problem acceptable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

USE  [File::Remote](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm) for Read/write/edit remote files transparently

Comment: File::Remote uses rcp/scp, muruga's question talks about FTP.

Answer (score 6):

From the `Net::FTP` documentation:

```
get ( REMOTE_FILE [, LOCAL_FILE [, WHERE]] )

Get REMOTE_FILE from the server and store locally. LOCAL_FILE may be a filename or a filehandle.
```

So just store the file directly into a variable attached to a filehandle.

```
use Net::FTP ();

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new('ftp.kde.org', Debug => 0)
  or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";

$ftp->login('anonymous', '-anonymous@')
  or die 'Cannot login ', $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd('/pub/kde')
  or die 'Cannot change working directory ', $ftp->message;

my ($remote_file_content, $remote_file_handle);
open($remote_file_handle, '>', \$remote_file_content);

$ftp->get('README', $remote_file_handle)
  or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->quit;

print $remote_file_content;
```

Comment: I gave File::Remote module is simple instead of Net::FTP

Comment: not intending to wake up an old post, but a quick question: When you create `$remote_file_content`, and then open it and write to it, do you need to close it as well?

Comment: KingsInnerSoul, please [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with that comment text, then delete your comment here.